# How to get closest rows in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this query:

```
(SELECT category FROM groups WHERE min < 52.850  LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT category FROM groups WHERE max > 52.850 AND min > 52.850 LIMIT 1)
```

[image]

I need to find a row where  `52.850 > 47.01 AND  52.850 < 52.99:`

```
4 | 47.01 | 52.99 | 0
```

Then to get prev and next rows

I have tried this:

```
SELECT category FROM groups WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE max <= 52.850 AND min <= 52.850 LIMIT 1)  OR id < (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE max <= 52.850 AND min <= 52.850 LIMIT 1) LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: No, I need to get two rows with ids: 3,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int, `min` int, `max` int, category int);
insert into t values
(1,null,10,1),(2,11,20,2),(3,21,30,4);

select * from
(
select * from t where id < (select id from t where 15 between `min` and `max`) order by id desc limit 1
) s
union 
(select * from t where id > (select id from t where 15 between `min` and `max`) order by id limit 1
) 
order by id;

+------+------+------+----------+
| id   | min  | max  | category |
+------+------+------+----------+
|    1 | NULL |   10 |        1 |
|    3 |   21 |   30 |        4 |
+------+------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below option-

```
(SELECT category 
FROM groups 
WHERE min < 52.850
ORDER BY min DESC
LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT category 
FROM groups 
WHERE max > 52.850 
AND min > 52.850
-- If you add the above condition, you will get 0,2
ORDER BY max > 52.850
LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: You get ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY with this query consider treating the 2 selects as sub queries.

Comment: If you add condition (AND min > 52.850) in the second query, you will get 0,2

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider the value if it is equal to or greater than 52.850. There is small edit in above answered query.

```
(SELECT category FROM groups WHERE min <= 52.850 ORDER BY min DESC LIMIT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT category FROM groups WHERE max >= 52.850 ORDER BY max LIMIT 1)
```

This should resolve the purpose.